STM32 SPI communication issue
I have two STM32 boards. First with STM32H755ZIT6 as SPI transmitter and second STM32F405RGT6 as a receiver.
Here is Transmitter's configuration. As you can see I set Transmitter's SPI clock to 42 MHz because Receiver SPI's max clock source is 42MHz.



SPI3 CS pin set as an Output and source code:
volatile uint8_t tx_done = 1U;

void HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback (SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi)
{
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI3_CS_Pin, 1);
   tx_done = 1;
}

Inside main function I do have
  uint8_t test[8] = {0xEB,0x9F,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  if(tx_done == 1U)
  {
      tx_done = 0U;
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI3_CS_Pin, 0);

      HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi3, press_data, 8);
  }

  HAL_Delay(500);
}

As you can see the logic is simple, it lows CS pin, then transmits via DMA and wait until Transmit complete interrupt.
this is the picture from logic analyzer and as you can see it works.

=================
Now the Receiver's configuration.



I set Receiver SPI3_CS pin as External interrupt on Falling edge, the logic is that to start receiving data as soon as CS pin goes low.
volatile u8 spi_rx_done = 0x01U;
volatile u8 pin_low = 0x00U;
u8 test[8];
u8 test2[8];

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  if(GPIO_Pin == SPI3_CS_Pin)
  {
      pin_low = 0x01U;
  }
}

void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback (SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi)
{
    memcpy(test2, test, 8);
    spi_rx_done = 0x01U;
}

and in the main function I do have
 while (1)
 {
   /* USER CODE END WHILE */

   /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */


  if(pin_low == 0x01U)
  {
      pin_low = 0U;

    if(spi_rx_done == 1)
    {
        spi_rx_done = 0;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, test2, 8, 1000);

        HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi3, test, 8);
    }
  }

ALSO my boards are connected via FPC cable and on the receiver's board I do have 100 ohm resistors on SPI lines.
Receiver's HAL SPI State is HAL_SPI_STATE_READY and ErrorCode is 0.
The problem is that I get valid data sometimes but mostly I receive junk data like this:

It's a simplest communication and I don't know what else to do. I tried different SPI transfer speed, different SPI clock speed but no result.
If you need an addition information , I can provide it.

Did you enable the interrupt and give power and clock  to every bus and peripheral that needs it?  Since your logic probe suggests transmit is working, The issue seems to be on the receive side.

@ScottSeidman Yes I did enable the interrupts for DMA and SPI too. Powers also are on. Yes the issue seems to be on the receive side but what it is I don't know

I don't see where you're setting up the initial HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA() on your slave device. your only call to HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA() occurs after there's been an initial SPI receive activity - but that's never going to happen.

@brhans sorry, edited the code. it's volatile u8 spi_rx_done = 0x01U; so first time it's 1 and HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA() is called for the first time.

What happens if you ignore the CS line in the receiver and continuously try to receive data? Maybe you need a bit more time between pulling CS low and the start of transmission.

Can you post an example of 'junk' data and the valid data it's supposed to be?

@BartvanIngenSchenau I tried to receive continuously but got junk data, instead of [0xEB,0x9F,2,3,4,5,6,7] i'm getting [07 75 cf 81 01 82 02 83]

@brhans , instead of [0xEB,0x9F,2,3,4,5,6,7] i'm getting [07 75 cf 81 01 82 02 83] , but sometimes I do get 0xEB,0x9F,2,3,4,5,6,7

@Alatriste, the garbage you receive appears to be 9 bits shifted from your expectation. If you ignore the first 9 bits, then the bit streams align again. Now the question is where does this 9-bit shift come from.

@BartvanIngenSchenau are you sure? how did you see it?

@BartvanIngenSchenau I uploaded junk data example after receiving the proper data. please look at.

@Alatriste, I wrote down both the correct and the garbage data in binary format as a sequence of bits. Then I did some pattern matching on the bit sequences and found a good match when I shifted the garbage by 9 positions. This was all a pen-and-paper exercise.

Toggle a bit when you enter and leave the interrupt to try to give you some vision.

You have an error in the way you're handling these external events in your slave. In its initial state, the GPIO interrupt has not yet fired, so pin_low is still 0, and your slave is not yet configured to receive over SPI. When the GPIO interrupt does fire for the 1st time and sets pin_low to 1 you main loop only then enabled SPI receive - by by the time that happens it's probably too late to catch some of the first bits the SPI master clocked out, and as a result you receive corrupted data.

You should probably call HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA()  at the start of your main loop so that your slave is ready to receive as soon as the master starts sending. I'm also not clear on why you're not using the Hardware NSS feature on your slave and doing it "manually" instead.

@brhans I'll try
